# How to break this string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string "10/15/2010"

I want to split this string into 10, 15, 2010 using c#, in VS 2010. i am not sure how to do this. If someone can tell me what function to use, it would be awesome.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Are you sure you want to break it up and not parse it as a date? DateTime offers functions for that.

Comment: what is your purpose? This will determine mode.

Comment: It could be that it's just a coincidence that it looks like a date.

Comment: @Lasse: It a much less likely coincidence that it's _today's_ date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string str = "10/15/2010";
string[] parts = str.split('/');
```

You now have string array `parts` that holds parts of that initial string.

Answer (score 10):

You probably want to call

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("10/15/2010", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Good call SLaks, While everyone is suggesting on [whether to use a shoe or a bottle](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) you suggest a hammer.

Comment: This is definitely a much better choice for converting date strings into actual dates.

Comment: The question was not how to parse a string to a date, it was how to split a string that happens to look like a date string into its components.  Is there any evidence in the question that he wants a date?  What if he wants to use the results as-is, not as dates?

Comment: @Cyberherbalist: That's why I said _probably_.  There are enough other answers that I didn't see the point in giving a `Split` call.

Comment: I always shy away from dateparsing routines that I don't have total control of as I live in the UK and if I had a pound for every time I've had headaches because of the whole DD/MM/YYYY MM/DD/YYYY issue I'd be on a yacht now and most probably not engaging in this thread.

Comment: @ElRonnoco: If you pass the correct culture, and/or call `ParseExact` with the format you're expecting, you won't have any trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

```
string date = "10/15/2010";
string[] dateParts = date.Split('/');
```

Answer (score 2):

Or do like a saw in a recent program (in Fortran which I am translating to C# below) ..

```
string[] parts = "10/15/2010".Split('/');
if( parts[0] == "01" ) month = 1;
if( parts[0] == "02" ) month = 2;
if( parts[0] == "03" ) month = 3;
if( parts[0] == "04" ) month = 4;
...
```

you get the idea. It kills me when people code it something crazy instead of calling a built in function to do the same thing.

( please don't flag me down, this is just a joke, not a real answer to the question )

Comment: just make sure that [the two digit representation of December isn't '12', but 'December'](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Cold-Date-Conversion.aspx) :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan to consume the information, you can choose strings, like has already been suggested, or parse it into a date then pull out the pieces.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("10/15/2010");
int y = date.year;
int m = date.Month;
int d = date.Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

"10/15/2010".Split('/')

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wanted the "split" elements to be strings as well:

```
string date = "10/15/2010";

string[] split = date.Split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

var date = "10/15/2010";

var split = date.Split('/')

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
string[] pieces = "10/15/2010".Split ('/');
```

Using [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).